# Random list elements spacing on Android Wear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wear-os

I faced with strangh problem.
I use `WearableListView` to show some list of data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adp_place_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="-4sp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adp_place_item_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="-4sp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Like this. 
And when data is populated, elemts has random spacing from the left in the list.

Here is screenshot.

[image: ScreenShot]

Maybe some `LayoutManager` need to be attached, like for `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No metter. Deal with it.
Strange Android Wear

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, what was it?

Comment: @wize, I added icons for rows(